# Setting an object in C# from a comma delimited string

Tags: c#

I am looping through a list of Umbraco nodes and setting the properties of my class using the property values on each node

```
foreach (var node in listOfNodeWithProperty)
{
    var faqProperties = new Faq
    {
        Question = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("question"),
        Answer = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("answer"),
        Schemes = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("schemes")
    };

    faqCollection.faqs.Add(faqProperties);

}
```

My Faq class is as follows

```
internal class Faq
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string Schemes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SchemeTypes> SchemeTypes { get; set; } 
}

internal class SchemeTypes
{
    public string SchemeType { get; set; }
}
```

All straight forward for strings but the values that I want to populate the SchemeTypes object is a comma delimited string. How do I take this string and create an array to populate SchemeTypes?

I want SchemeTypes as an object because my final output will be JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to split on commas and project from that to `SchemeTypes` objects:

```
SchemeTypes = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("schemeTypes")
                  .Split(',')
                  .Select(t => new SchemeTypes { SchemeType = t })
                  .ToList() // Materialize the result
```

I would caution the use of `SchemaTypes` as a type name when it represents a *single* type though. I'd consider something like:

```
internal class SchemeType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

That's if you *really* need a class for it though. You could just have an `IEnumerable<string>` property in `Faq`, and it would generate JSON of

```
schemeTypes = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

Whereas with the extra class you'll get

```
schemeTypes = [
   { "name": "a" },
   { "name": "b" },
   { "name": "c" }
]
```

Are you sure you want the latter formatting?

If you're happy with the property being an `IEnumerable<string>`, you can just stick with the result of `string.Split`:

```
var faqProperties = new Faq
{
    Question = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("question"),
    Answer = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("answer"),
    Schemes = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("schemes"),
    SchemeTypes = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("schemeTypes").Split(',')
};
```

Comment: Thanks Daisy. I think the `IEnumerable<string>` is far better than the latter formatting. So if I just want the IEnumerable<string>, do I still need to materialize the result?

Comment: @Mike: You can just use `string.Split` in that case. I'll add details to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Daisy - one last thing - what would be to check if the string is empty so as to avoid an error on the split?

Comment: @Mike: Do you mean empty or null? You should think about what you want the result to be in each case, and probably look at `StringSplitOptions` too. If it gets more than a single expression can easily handle, I'd extract it into a separate method. The `?.` operator could be useful though: `node.GetPropertyValue<string>("schemeTypes")?.Split(',')` will return null if `GetPropertyValue<string>("schemeTypes")` returns null.

Answer (score 3):

Do you just mean this?:

```
new Faq
{
    Question = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("question"),
    Answer = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("answer"),
    Schemes = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("schemes"),
    SchemeTypes = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("schemetypes")
                      .Split(',')
                      .Select(s => new SchemeType { SchemeType = s })
}
```

Basically just using `.Split()` to convert the comma-delimited string into a collection and then `.Select()` to project that collection into a new collection of the desired type.